# Two different font sizes within a same <input type="number">

Tags: html, css, font-size

I'd like to use a smaller font-size **for decimals only** using an input element:

```
<input id="amount" type="number" value="42.00" />
```

**I'm trying to achieve this**:

[image: Example]

It does not seem supported by default in HTML, any easy trick?

Comment: Use [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) instead.

Comment: Maybe split the amount in an integer and a decimal part and trigger something on entry of '.'? Just thinking aloud. I like the `contenteditable` idea too, but that depends on how much effort you are willing to put into this, I guess. Also: you could try to vary CSS `input[pattern] { .... }`